# Prove that $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ has no subgroups of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

To prove this I've thought of the following idea:

Suppose there exists $S$ a subgroup such that $\#(\mathbb{Q}:S)=n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\{a_1, a_2,..., a_n\}$ is a set with a representative from each class of $S$. My idea now is to define $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x-a_i \notin S \ \ \forall i \in \{ 1, 2, ..., n\}$ this way we see that the class of $x$ is different from all the classes with a representative $a_i$ therefore there has to be an infinite number of classes.

However I fail to find a way to define $x$ this way. I'd apreciate some help with the problem wether by giving a solution or a hint in case its possible to solve it this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @lulu. That definitely gives a solution to the same problem but I was looking for some help on the way I tried to solve it.

Comment: All you did was to restate the problem, I don't see any place to start from what you wrote. Well, nothing that doesn't look like the duplicate. I suggest looking at the duplicate.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724728/there-is-no-proper-subgroup-of-mathbb-q-of-finite-index) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981823/showing-that-mathbbq-has-no-subgroups-of-finite-index-without-using-quotie) are more duplicates.

Comment: A divisible group has no proper subgroup of finite index.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf Q$ has a proper subgroup $H$ of finite index then it would have a maximal proper subgroup (a proper subgroup contained in no other) since $\mathbf Q/H$ is a nontrivial finite group, nontrivial finite groups have maximal subgroups, and there is a natural correspondence between the subgroups of $\mathbf Q$ containing $H$ and the subgroups of $\mathbf Q/H$.

Example 2.2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/zorn1.pdf) shows $\mathbf Q$ has no maximal subgroups.